# .htaccess directory name uppercase to lowercase

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, uppercase, lowercase

http://website.com/SUBfolder/filename.php

I need to convert "SUBfolder" to "subfolder".

I do not want to change the case of the actual filename only if its a directory I need it to be lowercase.

I do not want this to be handled in php. I need it to be handled directly in htaccess.

**This is not the same question as other posts because I do not want to edit anything accept htaccess and I do not want to edit apache files**

Comment: This is not a duplicate as that thread does not answer the question I asked with my requirements.

Comment: In case anyone does need a solution I went against my own requirements and used an apache module to do the job: http://serverfault.com/questions/177647/convert-and-redirect-url-in-uppercase-to-lowercase-using-htaccess

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The question clearly asks for a .htaccess-only solution, he doesn't want to edit the configuration file.